# Can I handle multiple operations with NSURLRequest?

Tags: nsurlconnection

I have an app that currently fetches a json array from a web service vis NSURLConnection and its delegate methods.  This returns an array of users.  But now I must fetch the users' points.  Do I need to create a new NSURLConnection to make the second call (but how would I handle the data coming in from the delegate methods for 2 different calls?) or is there a way to create multiple operations or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each request you need a new `NSURLConnection`.

The best approach for your problem is to have

1. A "Model" which represents your users. E.g. an `NSArray` of dictionaries, where one dictionary represents one user.
2. One dedicated class that fetches the users array. It uses the asynchronous pattern, similar like `NSOperation`, possibly it becomes a subclass of `NSOperation`. Basically, it has a `start` method and a completion block. This class encapsulates a `NSURLConnection` as an ivar, the *response data*, and possibly a few more state information, like the `NSURLResponse` object and perhaps a `NSError` object. Let this class have a completion block with a parameter which returns either the expected result or an `NSError`. The completion block may have this signature:

   ```
   typedef void (^completion_block_t)(id result);
   ```
3. One other dedicated class that fetches a user's "point". Basically, the same class as above.
4. A asynchronous wrapper method with the following signature:

   ```
   typedef void (^completion_block_t)(id result);

   -(void) fetchUsersAndPoints:(completion_block_t)completionHandler;
   ```

   which first fetches the users array. Then, when finished successfully, for each user it fetches the user's "point". When all asynchronous requests have been finished or when an error occurred, it calls the completion handler.

First hint: you need to use "continuation" which "chains" two or more asynchronous functions. Basic principle:

```
      asyncA(^(id resultA) {
           asyncB(^id(id resultB){
               ... 
               asyncC(^id(id result){
                   NSLog(@"result: %@", result);    
               });
          }       
      });
```

This will read: perform asyncA. If finished perform asyncB. If finished perform asyncC.

Second hint: you can invoke the "point requests" simultaneously.

Third hint: you know when all "point requests" have been finished, when the completion handler of the "point request" have been called N times, where N is the number of users.

First caution:

You possibly need to synchronize the access to the models array, and also the access to the counter N from within the completion blocks.

Second caution:

When you have too many "point requests" you likely need to utilize a queue (`NSOperationQueue` for example) where you limit the maximum number of concurrent requests performed by `NSURLConnection` instances.

Comment: Ok so as of now I create my NSURLRequest & NSURLConnection in my viewDidLoad and then in connectionDidFinishLoading I receive the data and populate my usersArray. I just created a HelperClass to handle the URL fetches.  So I can either create NSOperation in vc class and call the helper class or the other option is use NSURLConnection delegate callbacks.  But where would I put those callback methods, in the helper class as well?

Comment: On gist, I've put a sample of a *very limited* class that encapsulates  a `NSURLConnection`, response data and other state info. That should give you a jump start: [SimpleGetHTTPRequest](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723)

Comment: Thx, I saw the class and I understand now that the SimpleGetHTTPRequest class can be called multiple times, once for each fetch. One last thing, how does the result object return to the viewcontroller and what does performSelectorOnMainThread:(start)? I had a different idea of how that worked (obviously wrong :))

Comment: The SimpleGetHTTPRequest class is "one shot" ;) That is, for every request you need to create a new one. Trust me, it's much simpler this way than having a HTTPRequest object which can execute several times. The result is provided through the completion block. If you had a property `result`, you would make the method block the thread until the result is available. The performSelector start ensures that the NSURLConnection will be scheduled on the main run loop. Due to synchronization, this is required in this implementation.

Comment: Note: the implementation of `SimpleGetHTTPRequest` can certainly be tweaked to issue several connection requests. However, this isn't tested in this code sample. I've made some fixes which ensures one cannot invoke `start` several times.

Comment: Yes its the completion block what im trying to understand. Ive read tutorials on blocks but tutorials are abstract until you see the need for it in your own code :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to have a property/ivar for each connection and then compare the delegate method's parameter with them. You can also get the request for the connection and get it's URL but this seems a bad approach because of the hardcoded data.

Comment: You mean I should name them connection1 and connection2 and then in the delegate method - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection I should check for the connection parameter?

Comment: Exactly. But use more explanatory names :)

Comment: And how exactly do I check if thats the connection name in the connectionDidFinishLoading method?

Comment: They are objects you should know how to compare them ;)